# Passing Server Side JavaScript Array to Client

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a select menu which I am displaying a list of options

I need to use server side JavaScript to call an external 3rd party db, and return and array. And I have client side JavaScript which is calling the array and populating the options in the select menu.

I am not certain how I can pass my array from the server side to the client side. I am good with my client side Javscript and with my server side JavaScript, just not certain as to how to pass my array from server to client side. Any input would be appreciated. Code is below.

**Server Side Javascript**

```
var arrayOptions = new Array();
arrayOptions= //call to DB is here      
for(var i = 0; i < arrayOptions.length; i++) {
  var opt = arrayOptions[i];
  arrayOptions.push(opt);
}
```

**Client Side JavaScript**

```
function getOptions(arrayOptions){
  var select = document.getElementById("selOption");
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOptions.length; i++) {
  var opt = arrayOptions[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(el);
 }
```

Comment: How to pass from server side to client side: AJAX. Asynchronous calls to the server return data to client. Easy but you need to try something first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, passing data from server to client usually involves AJAX requests. For instance, the POST request, can be sent to the server and then the server can respond to it however you'd like. I'm not sure how you're running your server, but I get a slight feeling you might not be running a server exactly. My advice is to learn how client/server communication works first, then sending an array is as easy as sending a string or number. Suggested reading:

[Node.js - serverside Javascript](https://nodejs.org/en/)
[AJAX - Sending data to the server without reloading the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

Comment: Thank you! Actually the server is a 3rd party SQL DB. That I can only GET data from.

Answer (score 0):

This function `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()` may helpful for you,if you are using using .NET Technologies.

Note : Hence you did not mention the technology thus I assume that,it should be .NET technologies and give my solution.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately not .NET. I am slightly restricted, due to the fact we are using some 3rd party properietary software. I am using HTML and standard Javascript (client side and server side).